# JQuery: img.src change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to build this simple gallery and it seems that Chrome's security doesn't support in-line jquery (it work on IE). (when I click on the *.mini* class images I want the *.show* class image to copy it's src). So I need to write a .js file. I just can't get it working. Some advice, please? I apologize for my bad English.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="galerie" align="center">
        <div class="mini">
            <img onClick="show1.src=imag01.src" id="imag01" src="img/pers/img1.jpg" alt="NO IMAGE"/>
            <img onClick="show1.src=imag02.src" id="imag02" src="img/pers/img2.jpg" alt="NO IMAGE"/>
            <img onClick="show1.src=imag03.src" id="imag03" src="img/pers/img3.jpg" alt="NO IMAGE"/>
            <img onClick="show1.src=imag04.src" id="imag04" src="img/pers/img4.jpg" alt="NO IMAGE"/>
            <img onClick="show1.src=imag05.src" id="imag05" src="img/pers/img5.jpg" alt="NO IMAGE"/>
            <img onClick="show1.src=imag06.src" id="imag06" src="img/pers/img6.jpg" alt="NO IMAGE"/>
            <img onClick="show1.src=imag07.src" id="imag07" src="img/pers/img7.jpg" alt="NO IMAGE"/>
            <img onClick="show1.src=imag08.src" id="imag08" src="img/pers/img8.jpg" alt="NO IMAGE"/>
            <img onClick="show1.src=imag09.src" id="imag09" src="img/pers/img9.jpg" alt="NO IMAGE"/>
        </div>  
        <div class="show" align="center">
           <img id="show1" src="img/img1.jpg" alt="NO IMAGE"/>
        </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
<style type="text/css">
            .mini img {
                height: 80px;
                border: 4px solid #C3C3C3;
                padding: 1px;
                margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
            }

            .mini img:hover {
                border: 4px solid #B08FAB;
                cursor:pointer;
            }

            .show img {
                border: 4px solid #C3C3C3;
                padding: 1px;
                height: 400px;
            }
            div.galerie{
                box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px #243139;
                z-index: 5;

            }
</style>
```

**JQuery *(not working)*:**

```
$(".mini img").click(function(){
            var imgsrc = jQuery(this).attr("src");
            $("#show1").attr("src", imgsrc);
});
```

Comment: You've included jQuery, right? And what errors do you get in your console?

Comment: Yes, I did. And I have no errors in console.

Answer (score 4):

```
jQuery("#show1 img").attr("src") = imgsrc;
```

^^ Is not how jQuery works. At all.

```
jQuery("#show1 img").attr("src", imgsrc);
```

^^ Is how jQuery does work.

[jQuery `.attr()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

EDIT: Your selector is wrong too. `#show1` is an image. So you should do:

```
jQuery("#show1").attr("src", imgsrc);
```

EDIT2: ...And you're getting the src of the first image for `imgsrc`, not the one that was clicked. Use `this`:

```
var imgsrc = jQuery(this).attr("src");
```

Or even

```
var imgsrc = this.src;
```

Comment: Still the same result.

Comment: Sorry for that. Updated. But it's got to be something else.

Comment: Found the other issue.

Comment: Same result. Anything else?